# SimpleDateFormat cast String não consulta no banco

Tags: php, java, mysql

Estou fazendo um aplicativo colaborativo para android, portanto, fiz um servidor em PHP, e envio os dados para este servidor.

Para uma determinada consulta preciso passar uma data, a partir de um Date Picker, eis o código:

```
String myFormat = "dd-MM-yy"; //In which you need put here
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
et_data.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
String data = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()) +"";
```

A variável data é passada para o servidor, porém no servidor ele não está interpretando como texto.

Mas se eu setar a variável data como:

```
String data = "12-02-2018";
```

Funciona normalmente. O valor que chega no servidor é este mesmo, e o type também é String.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Não deu pra entender seu problema, testei seu codigo e está funcionando, ao menos como imagino que deveria, ja que nao esta claro seu problema: https://ideone.com/ntrhqD

Comment: Pois é , pra mim o código parece certo. Quando recebo no servidor PHP ele não interpreta isso -> (String data = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()) +"";), como uma String.

Comment: Entao o problema nao é no lado do java.

Comment: Como está a receber isso no lado do servidor em PHP ? De que forma é que faz o "envio" da informação ?

Comment: Você disse que se setar a variável como `12-02-2018` funciona. Mas o `SimpleDateFormat` que vc criou usa `dd-MM-yy`, que só imprime o ano com dois dígitos. Tente trocar para `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: Outro detalhe é que o método `format()` já retorna uma `String`, e concatenar com a `String` vazia (a parte no final `+""`) é redundante e pode ser removido. Então ficaria somente `String data = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu format para `dd-MM-yyyy` porque se colocar com 2 y somemente ele vai pegar o valor literal e não numérico.

Ex:

```
String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```